# Sending array to REST API from Appery project

Tags: jquery, json, rest, appery.io

I have an external rest api that expects to get an array of json objects.
How can I rest in javascript?
I tried like this but got an error message:

```
send_ivrs.execute({
data: [{
"company": "test",
"phone": "0123456789"
}]
});
```

The error I got (400 - bad request):

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"test"})
> into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' because the type requires
> a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this
> error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change
> the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a
> primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or
> List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
> JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
> deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath '0', line 1, position 5.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general requirement for API calls. API Express, and Server Code [support](https://docs.appery.io/reference/servercode-xhr-send#examples) object body request, not an array. Please send the object with the property = array, instead of the array directly. I mean the request should be like:

```
send_ivrs.execute({
   data: {"myArray": [{
      "company": "test",
      "phone": "0123456789"
   }]}
});
```